# go install fails when CGO_ENABLED=0

Tags: go

I have a strange issue:

`go install` works fine.

However `CGO_ENABLED=0` gives me an error:

```
➜ CGO_ENABLED=0 go install   
go install net: open /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/net.a: permission denied
```

I don't get why it thinks that net package changed.

I was trying to resolve it by doing

```
➜ go clean -i
```

and by

```
➜ rm -r $GOPATH/pkg
```

which didn't help.
Here is my setup:

```
➜ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/aberezhynskyi/work/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build254491808=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
➜ go version
go version go1.7.1 linux/amd64
```

Comment: You probably don't have write permission for GOROOT. Does it work with `-installsuffix nocgo`?

Comment: @JimB, fails with `go install runtime/internal/sys: mkdir /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64_nocgo: permission denied`. I'm not running it as a super user

Comment: So I should run it as a super user? I'm just finding it weird that doing `go install` in a project tries to install `net` package.

Comment: It would probably be better to make your GOROOT writable by your user. It needs to install the `net` package because that packages uses CGO, so it needs to be re-compiled.

Comment: @JimB thank you for the help